# Change table Field Place Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I got Table MyUsers fields are  username , userid, password then i got many records in this table. I want to change fields place  userid,username,password in mysql. How can I update it? Any Code or Method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ALTER TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) with `AFTER`.

```
ALTER TABLE MyUsers MODIFY COLUMN username <USERNAME'S TYPE> <NULLABLE?>
    AFTER userid
```

You could also use `MODIFY COLUMN` on `userid` with `FIRST`.

Answer (score 0):

Also, phpMyAdmin has a "Move column" feature to accomplish this.